# Why does Gsub not work when converting units?

Tags: r

I was wondering if anyone could help point me in the right direction in how to fix my function. Basically, I have a list of measurements written in different units (e.g. ft, cm, m) and I've been writting a function to put them all into the same base units of cm i.e.:

Turn this:

```
5_ft_7
157_cm
5_ft_11
167_cm
1.65_m
187_cm
1.71_m
188_cm
5_ft_2
5_ft_5
```

Into this:

```
170.180
157.000
155.194
167.000
165.000
187.000
171.000
188.000
157.480
165.100
```

Using this function I've created:

```
  Conv.Question2 <- function(x) {
    (Conv.ft <- function(x) {
      Data_original.ft <- (x)
      Data_original.ft <-lapply(Data_original.ft, gsub, pattern= "_ft_", replacement =".")
      k <- as.numeric(suppressWarnings(x)) 
      Feet.cm <- (floor(k)*30.48)  #Feet in cm
      Inches.cm <- data.frame(((k-floor(k))*10)*2.54) #Inches in cm
      Total.cm <- data.frame(Feet.cm, Inches.cm)
      Final <- data.frame(Total.cm %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% mutate(Total = rowSums(.)))
      print(data.frame(Final$Total))
    })
      (Conv.cm <- function(x) {
      Data_original.cm <- (x)
      Data_original.cm <- lapply(Data_original.cm, gsub, pattern= "_cm", replacement ="")
      l <- as.numeric(suppressWarnings(x)) 
      Total.cm <- data.frame(l)
      Final.cm <- data.frame(Total.cm %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% mutate(Total = rowSums(.)))
      print(data.frame(Final.cm$Total))
    })
      (Conv.m <- function(x) {
      Data_original.m <- (x)
      Data_original.m <- lapply(Data_original.m, gsub, pattern= "_m", replacement ="")
      m <- as.numeric(suppressWarnings(x)) 
      Total.m <- data.frame(m*100)
      Final.m <- data.frame(Total.m %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% mutate(Total = rowSums(.)))
      print(data.frame(Final.m$Total))
    })
    Height_ft <- Conv.ft(x)
    Height_cm <- Conv.cm(x)
    Height_m <- Conv.m(x)
    Test104 <- cbind(Height_ft,Height_cm,Height_m)
    Test105 <- data.frame(rowSums(Test104, na.rm=TRUE))
    colnames(Test105) <- c("Height(cm)")
    Test105[Test105 == 0] <-NA
    cat("\014") #Clears console
    print(Test105)
  }
```

(and yes, I do realise that my feet and inches conversion still needs work, but I'm fairly sure that is something I can fix myself)

The issue is that whenever I run it, there are no warning messages of concern, but it just produces a list of NAs. Hopefully, I am close to fixing it, but after trying several different methods, I have so far not been able to work out what is going wrong.

Any advice on what part(s) of this function are causing it to fail would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The code is quite hard to read, and this is partly because there’s a lot of unnecessary, cluttered code. For example, you’re using a lot of unnecessary parentheses. You also don’t need `suppressWarnings(x)`: just accessing a variable will never cause warnings. The indentation is also not consistent. And as far as code design goes, a function shouldn’t both compute a result and print it. Instead, only return it, do the printing elsewhere, if necessary.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an overly complex approach. I would probably boil it all down to a single function that uses `ifelse` to parse each measurement type:

```r
convert_all <- function(text)
{
  suppressWarnings(
    ifelse(grepl("_m", text), 100 * as.numeric(gsub("_m", "", text)),
       ifelse(grepl("_cm", text), as.numeric(gsub("_cm", "", text)),
              sapply(strsplit(text, "_ft_"), function(x) {
                x <- as.numeric(x)
                (x[1] * 12 + x[2]) * 2.54
              })))
  )
}
```

So, in your case, we would have:

```r
measurements <- c("5_ft_7", "157_cm", "5_ft_11", "167_cm", "1.65_m", "187_cm", 
                  "1.71_m", "188_cm", "5_ft_2", "5_ft_5")

convert_all(measurements)
#> [1] 170.18 157.00 180.34 167.00 165.00 187.00 171.00 188.00 157.48 165.10
```

---

An alternative approach if you prefer to see your working and avoid `suppressWarnings` calls, both of which might help in debugging, is to break the problem down into little sub-problems by creating a function to convert each measurement type, and a function to distribute the work between these functions appropriately:

```r
as_metres <- function(text) 100 * as.numeric(gsub("_m", "", text))

as_cm     <- function(text) as.numeric(gsub("_cm", "", text))

as_ft     <- function(text) sapply(strsplit(text, "_ft_"), 
                               function(x) {
                                 x <- as.numeric(x)
                                 (x[1] * 12 + x[2]) * 2.54
                                })

convert_all <- function(text)
{
  result <- numeric(length(text))
  result[grepl("_cm", text)] <- as_cm(grep("_cm", text, value = TRUE))
  result[grepl("_m", text)] <- as_metres(grep("_m", text, value = TRUE))
  result[grepl("_ft", text)] <- as_ft(grep("_ft", text, value = TRUE))
  return(result)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- as_tibble(
  c("5_ft_7", "157_cm", "5_ft_11", "167_cm", "1.65_m", "187_cm", "1.71_m", "188_cm", "5_ft_2", "5_ft_5")
)
df %>%
  separate(value, into = c("big", "unit", "small"), fill = "right") %>%
  mutate(small = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(small)),
         big = as.numeric(ifelse(str_detect(unit, "\\d"), paste0(big, unit), big))) %>%
  transmute(height = case_when(
    unit == "ft" ~ big * 30.48 + small * 2.54,
    unit == "cm" ~ big,
    str_detect(unit, pattern = "\\d") ~ big
  )) %>%
  pull(height)
#> [1] 170.18 157.00 180.34 167.00 165.00 187.00 171.00 188.00 157.48 165.10
```

Answer (score 2):

## Reviewing code in question

Taking Conv.ft as an example it replaces `_ft_` with a dot but then tries to convert everything to numeric including the non-`_ft_` components causing the introduction of NA's.  Instead determine which components contain `_ft_` and then convert those (using sub, not gsub since we only want one replacement per component) and return 0 for the others.  Note that sub and gsub are vectorized already so they don't need lapply. Now when we convert to numeric no NA's will be produced.
Putting  all this together use this to set k:

```
  k <- as.numeric(ifelse(grepl("_ft_", x), sub("_ft_", ".", x), 0))
```

Make analogous changes in the other Conv.* functions.

### A different approach.

Here is a function which uses a slightly different approach. It still uses separate functions, ft, cm and m.

The function f takes a units string, u, such as "ft", "cm" or "m" and a string, x, such as "5    7" or "157   ".  It converts x to a numeric vector and then uses do.call to call the function whose name is in u using the numeric vector as argument.  gsub is used to extract the units and numbers strings and mapply applies f to those.

```
Conv2cm <- function(x) {
  ft <- function(x) 2.54 * sum(x * c(12, 1))
  cm <- function(x) x
  m <- function(x) 100 * x
  
  f <- function(u, x) do.call(u, list(scan(text = x, quiet = TRUE)))
  units <- gsub("[0-9._]", "", x)  # remove all digits, . and _
  nums <- gsub("[^0-9.]", " ", x)  # replace all but digit & . w space
  mapply(f, units, nums, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}

Conv2cm(measurements)
##  [1] 170.18 157.00 180.34 167.00 165.00 187.00 171.00 188.00 157.48 165.10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution with some `purrr` functionality:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data.frame(x) %>%
  mutate(
    x = sub("_cm", ".000", x),
    x = sub("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)_m", "\\1\\2", x),
    temp = ifelse(grepl("ft", x), strsplit(x, "_ft_"), NA),
    x = ifelse(grepl("ft", x), 
               map_dbl(temp, function(x) (as.numeric(x)[1]*12 + as.numeric(x)[2])*2.54),
               x),
    x = as.numeric(x)
  ) %>%
  select(-temp)
        x
1  170.18
2  157.00
3  180.34
4  167.00
5  165.00
6  187.00
7  171.00
8  188.00
9  157.48
10 165.10
```

Here's a stepwise, mostly `base R` procedure:

```
# values with "_cm":
cm <- grep("_cm", x, value = TRUE)
cm_new <- as.numeric(sub("_cm", ".000", cm))

# values with "_m":
m <- grep("_m", x, value = TRUE)
m_new <- as.numeric(gsub("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)?_m", "\\1\\2", m))

# values with "_ft_":
ft <- grep("_ft", x, value = TRUE)
ft_0 <- gsub("(\\d+)_ft_(\\d+)", "\\1.\\2", ft)
library(purrr)
ft_new <- map_dbl(strsplit(ft_0, "\\."), function(x) (as.numeric(x)[1]*12 + as.numeric(x)[2])*2.54)

# now concatenate:
all_new <- c(cm_new, m_new, ft_new)
```

Result:

```
all_new
 [1] 157.00 167.00 187.00 188.00 165.00 171.00 170.18 180.34 157.48 165.10
```

Data:

```
x <- c("5_ft_7",
      "157_cm",
      "5_ft_11",
      "167_cm","1.65_m",
      "187_cm","1.71_m",
      "188_cm","5_ft_2",
      "5_ft_5")
```

Answer (score 1):

A flexible approach than can handle almost any type of measurement you can throw at it..
for distances, it can handle:

> ```
> angstrom, nm, um, mm, cm, dm, m, km, inch, ft, 
> yd, fathom, mi, naut_mi, au, light_yr,
> parsec, point
> ```

Core of the conversion is the `conv_unit()` function from the `measurements`-package

```
library(data.table)
library(measurements)
DT <- fread("5_ft_7
157_cm
5_ft_11
167_cm
1.65_m
187_cm
1.71_m
188_cm
5_ft_2
5_ft_5", header = FALSE)

#add rowid
DT[, id := .I]
# split on _
DT[, c("val1", "units", "val2") := tstrsplit(V1, "_")][]
# add second unit vor inches
DT[units == "ft", units2 := "inch"]
#         V1 id val1 units val2 units2
# 1:  5_ft_7  1    5    ft    7   inch
# 2:  157_cm  2  157    cm <NA>   <NA>
# 3: 5_ft_11  3    5    ft   11   inch
# 4:  167_cm  4  167    cm <NA>   <NA>
# 5:  1.65_m  5 1.65     m <NA>   <NA>
# 6:  187_cm  6  187    cm <NA>   <NA>
# 7:  1.71_m  7 1.71     m <NA>   <NA>
# 8:  188_cm  8  188    cm <NA>   <NA>
# 9:  5_ft_2  9    5    ft    2   inch
#10:  5_ft_5 10    5    ft    5   inch

# melt to long format
DT.melt <- melt(DT, id.vars = "id", 
                measure.vars = patterns(unit = "^units", 
                                        value = "^val"),
                na.rm = TRUE)
#    id variable unit value
# 1:  1        1   ft     5
# 2:  2        1   cm   157
# 3:  3        1   ft     5
# 4:  4        1   cm   167
# 5:  5        1    m  1.65
# 6:  6        1   cm   187
# 7:  7        1    m  1.71
# 8:  8        1   cm   188
# 9:  9        1   ft     5
#10: 10        1   ft     5
#11:  1        2 inch     7
#12:  3        2 inch    11
#13:  9        2 inch     2
#14: 10        2 inch     5

# split by unit
L <- split(DT.melt, by = "unit")
# calculate in centimeter
L <- lapply(L, function(x){
  x[, value_cm := conv_unit(as.numeric(value), 
                            unique(unit), "cm")]
})
# bind together and summarise, join on DT
DT[rbindlist(L)[, .(value_cm = sum(value_cm)), by = .(id)],
   in_cm := i.value_cm, on = .(id)]
#         V1 id val1 units val2 units2  in_cm
# 1:  5_ft_7  1    5    ft    7   inch 170.18
# 2:  157_cm  2  157    cm <NA>   <NA> 157.00
# 3: 5_ft_11  3    5    ft   11   inch 180.34
# 4:  167_cm  4  167    cm <NA>   <NA> 167.00
# 5:  1.65_m  5 1.65     m <NA>   <NA> 165.00
# 6:  187_cm  6  187    cm <NA>   <NA> 187.00
# 7:  1.71_m  7 1.71     m <NA>   <NA> 171.00
# 8:  188_cm  8  188    cm <NA>   <NA> 188.00
# 9:  5_ft_2  9    5    ft    2   inch 157.48
#10:  5_ft_5 10    5    ft    5   inch 165.10
```